# Is X11's design tightly coupled to a program's usage capabilities?

Tags: events, user-interface, x11

Say I want to create my own button with an arduino. Would I be able to call an X11 Event with that button every time it was clicked so that my program running would see it as a mouse click? Does the window currently have to be in focus for this to happen? Is the mechanism behind graphical user interfaces (X11) tightly dependent on the conventional windowing system, mouse, keyboard, and screen?

Comment: Are you running Linux on the Arduino?  I don't get this.

Comment: Nono, the arduino is connected to my linux box, and I plan on writing a program on my linux box that listens to the signals that the arduino sends when the button is pressed. I'd really like for that program to just simply relay the signal into a button that got pressed on a different GUI program.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing man, this has been bugging me lately.

Comment: You probably want something like this: http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html

Comment: You may use `XSendEvent`. If your application does not specifically ignore events sent with `XSendEvent` you are all set. (It may be wise to ignore such events for security reasons, many X11 applications do that.) The window does not need to be in focus ("focus" in X11 refers strictly to the keyboard). If your program does ignore such events, you may want to use the `XTest` extension functions instead. It's more cumbersome to use then `XSendEvent`, but it will work with any application.